# A perl Script to Delete trailing spaces in a csv file

Tags: perl, csv

I am new to Perl Programming. 
I have a CSV File with N fields in which Nth field is having Trailing Spaces for all the records. I want to remove all this Trailing Spaces.Please help me in this.

I have used this substitution in a loop. But it has given me empty file

```
s/\s+$//
```

Example File

```
123,ABCD,"AC,BD",21/12/2013        
134,CDEF,"CD,BD,ED",23/11/2013     
987,TGYH,"HY,-.FDDS",20/11/2013
```

Output

```
123,ABCD,"AC,BD",21/12/2013
134,CDEF,"CD,BD,ED",23/11/2013
987,TGYH,"HY,-.FDDS",20/11/2013
```

Please let me know if you need more details.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your input doesn't show any trailing spaces, and the regex looks as though it removes trailing spaces from the end of line, not the end of the Nth field. Removing trailing spaces from the end of a line is trivial. Removing trailing spaces from the end of a quote-enclosed field midway through a line is considerably harder (you'd start with [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) and then work with the regex applied to the fields it reads).

Answer (score 2):

Your regex seems good.  You could say:

```
perl -ple 's/\s+$//' filename
```

To save the changes in-place to the file, say:

```
perl -i -ple 's/\s+$//' filename
```

Comment: Please send me the Full script

Comment: @user2992186 This is the full script.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to remove the leading and trailing spaces in the csv file:

1. Open the input file

   ```
   OPEN FILE, "<$input_file";
   ```
2. Looping each and every row in the file to do trim of each row in the csv file.In the while loop use regex to trim the leading and trailing of the spaces for each field

   ```
   while(my $row = <FILE>)
   {
       $row =~ 's/\s//g';
   }
   ```

This will give you the results you are expecting

Comment: This will delete _all_ whitespace, not only leading/trailing one. It would squash `"foo bar"` to `"foobar"`. And it won't change the input file, just do the replacement and throw it away. `OPEN` should be `open`. `$row =~ 's/\s//g';` should be `$row =~ s/\s//g;` (without quotes).